# Is it possible to resubmit a task to a Spring @Async method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-async

I have a Spring method annotated with `@Async`

```
@Async
public void doSomething(long id, String text) {
    //do something
}
```

The method invokes a remote service, which occasionally times out. Is there a way to catch the timeout and resubmit the task to the `@Async` method N seconds later?

I doubt calling the annotated method from inside itself will work because Spring uses a pointcut to intercept invocations.

The only way I can think of is to override `AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.handleError` to rebuild an instanceof `MethodInvocation` and then call a copy of 
 `AsyncExecutionInterceptor.invoke` that lets me specify a delay.

Is there another way? Perhaps someone has already done it?

---

*An Aside*

*I can imagine a solution whereby `@Async` is extended to specify cases for retry, in much the same way that transactions are managed in Spring but this is more fundamental than the theoretical solution described above!*

```
@Async(retryOn=TimeoutException.class, maxRetries=2, delayStrategy=DelayStrategy.DOUBLE)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-retry-module/

Comment: It might do, I wasn't aware of that project. I'll have to have a look at it.

Comment: I've had a look at the Spring Retry Module, and it doesn't seem to release the calling thread during the retry. I'm specifically looking for a solution that frees the thread during the backoff period.

Comment: Spring is pretty configurable, so it's quite possible that you can code this retry policy (or however it's named) yourself.